# Python in VSCode can't find module even changed to a right environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using `VSCode` for `python` programming. The interpreters are from `Anaconda` (Python 3.7 in the latest version of `Anaconda`). I've added the `Anaconda` folder path into the system environment variables:

[image]

I've installed packages `numpy` and `numba` via `conda`, and I created an environment which contains those packages:

[image]

And the current `VSCode` is working under that environment:

[image]

It works fine in `PyCharm` by using the same interpreter/environment, but
when I switched to `VSCode` it always gets me error: `ImportError: No module named numba`. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: How are you executing the code? Is the base environment activated before you execute the code?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to manually add environment in VS Code. Remove all the path you have manually added. Bring up the Extensions view by clicking on the Extensions icon in the Activity Bar on the side of VS Code or the View: Extensions command (⇧⌘X (Windows, Linux Ctrl+Shift+X)).

Search for Anaconda extension. Install and refresh your VS Code. Open your project folder and click on of your .py file. VS Code will search all available Pythons in your system.

On the bottom right you should be able to select a correct environments

Comment: I didn't manually type the path in setting, I chose Python interpreter from Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), "Python: Select Interpreter" as https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments . Then the path auto filled with the path shown above. The path is the same as  that in Pycharm, but can't find the module in VSCode